# Does Safety in Swift affect Performance?

Tags: swift

While learning Swift, I have seen many cases of safe code vs. unsafe code. A perfect example of this is

**as?** and **as!**

**as?**, from my understanding tries to type cast, but if it doesn't cast, returns nil.

**as!**, from my understanding, tries to type cast, and crashes if it fails.

My question, is why does **as!**, (and other unsafe syntax with safe counterparts, for that matter) exist? Obviously **as?** is the better choice. The only answer I could come up with is that maybe using **as!** is faster for the compiler to compile, and therefore is mainly an optimization piece of syntax.

I'm just curious to know I'm right about safe syntax being a bit slower to compile, since performance matters to me a great deal.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Actually there are some shades between black/unsafe (`as!`) and white/safe (`as?`)

Comment: To fill holes in the type system. It's a lot easier to know and apply knowledge of certain truths (of the types of the data at work in your program), then to formally prove them to the compiler. A type system is really just a way of expressing proofs to a compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say, `as!` should hardly ever be used. There are a few cases, though, where due to legacy issues, the compiler doesn't know what type something should be, even though the developer does. One example of this is the `NSCopying` protocol. Because Objective-C was not as strict about type safety as Swift, `copy()` returns an `id`, which is bridged to `Any` in Swift. However, when you use `copy()`, `mutableCopy()`, and friends, you usually know exactly what type you will get out of it, so `as!` is typically used to force a cast to the correct type.

```
let aString: NSAttributedString = ...
let mutableAString = aString.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableAttributedString
```

Comment: Why was this answer accepted? It makes no attempt to answer the question about performance. All it does is give an example of where `as!` is probably safe.

Comment: The question was, "My question, is why does as!, (and other unsafe syntax with safe counterparts, for that matter) exist?" Performance was merely the OP's speculation as to the reason. My answer is that it is not performance-related, but rather that `as!` is sometimes safe. I wouldn't actually expect performance to be any different at all, since `as!` still has to check the type in order to know whether to crash or not.

Comment: Charles, I agree with your reading (though you should incorporate that comment into your answer, to explain why you didn't actually answer the asked question). My only quibble is the contention one "should hardly ever" use `as!`. I disagree. Use the right tool for the right job: Sometimes cast can never fail (except for programming errors that are fatal, anyway), in which case `as!` is not only acceptable, but arguably preferable. But if the cast can realistically fail for _any_ reason, then of course, use `as?`.

Comment: Well, most of the time the cast *can* fail, and the times when you know it won't fall into a minority. But the number of times that can happen is not zero, so `as!` exists. As for the question, I decided to interpret the "asked question" as the one stated in the body of the actual post, since that's clearly the question the OP was trying to answer.

Answer (score 2):

This question is based upon a false premise: The primary choice of `as?` vs `as!` is not generally one of performance. Sure, `as!` potentially might be a bit more efficient, but in an optimized build, the difference is generally negligible.

One chooses `as!` vs `as?` based upon the context:

- If the cast can possibly fail at runtime, then you'd use `as?`. Of course you add code to check to see whether the cast succeeded or not.

  A common example of a cast that could fail would be whenever the source of the data is some external source (e.g. user input or a network request). A user could paste text values into a field in which you were expecting only numeric values. An external web server could be unavailable or it could even return data in an unexpected format. You'd want to use `as?` to detect these situations and handle it gracefully.
- But if the cast can not possibly fail at runtime, you use `as!`. But you do so less for performance reasons than for reasons of clarity and writing concise code.

  A common example of a cast that cannot fail would be when retrieving a cell prototype from a storyboard, where you know the base type was set in Interface Builder, though the Cocoa API cannot know this. It would be ineffiencient to add a lot of code checking to see if the base type was set correctly (especially since this would be a fatal programming error, anyway) and leads to code with a lot of syntactic noise with no benefit. And if you don't do it correctly, you could easily accidentally suppress an error that you really would want to flush out during the testing process, making it harder to find the problem. This is a good use case for `as!` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

**as!** is not unsafe unless your code before it has failed to ensure the cast can't fail.  Imagine a situation where your code has already verified the object can indeed be cast to a particular protocol.  If for whatever reason you find it convenient to not create a new local variable of that type and cast the first variable to it, then using as! can be appropriate.

The same logic goes for implicitly unwrapped optionals.  Since when your view controller is instantiated, an IBOutlet property can't be assigned yet (storyboard hasn't loaded yet), the property has to be optional.  But it's irksome to have to use the property as an optional throughout the class when you know the storyboard has loaded.  In fact, if there is a problem with locating the storyboard element and assigning it, a 100% guaranteed crash is desired so that the developer can always spot and fix the problem.

So returning to **as!**, this raises a second case of when it's appropriate to use: whenever a crash is the most desirable outcome of the failed cast.

So it's not about compiler speed.  It's about code logic convenience.  There are appropriate times to use it, and for those times, it's a more compact and easier to read way of representing your logic goals.

Comment: I will give another common example - downcasting `URLResponse` to `HTTPURLResponse`. It's one of the cases when we can be sure the cast always succeeds and if it doesn't, we did something very wrong. In my experience many programmers are solving a failed `as?` using a `fatalError(...)` anyway...

Answer (score 0):

You can investigate this question for yourself by compiling something like

```
func f(a: Any) -> Int {
    (a as! Int) + 5
}
```

vs.

```
func f(a: Any) -> Int {
    ((a as? Int) ?? 3) + 5
}
```

With the Swift 4 compiler, running `swiftc -O -emit-assembly` on this Swift code produces extremely similar output, which should square with your understanding of how `as!` works and how we would implement it if it wasn't part of the language:

```
func forceCast<T>(_ subject: Any) -> T {
    return subject as? T ?? fatalError("Could not cast \(subject) to \(T)")
}
```

It's worth noting, as SmartCat already alluded to, that `as!` isn't actually "unsafe" in the sense that the Swift compiler authors define that word; because it, like `as?`, actually specifically checks the type of `subject`. There is a unsafe-in-the-swift-sense force cast in swift; it's called, unsurprisingly, `unsafeBitCast`; and is equivalent to a C/Objective-C cast; it doesn't check types and just assumes you knew what you were doing. Will it be faster than `as`? Without a doubt.

So, to answer your title's question: yes, safety has a cost in Swift. The flip side of the coin is that if you write code that avoids casts and optionality, Swift can (in theory) optimize your code far more aggressively than languages that make less strong safety guarantees.

To answer your actual question; there's no difference between `as?` and `as!` in terms of performance.

Other's have already covered why `as!` exists; it's so you can tell the compiler "I can't explain why to you, but this will always work; trust me".